# Continually Validating Integers

Tags: java, swing, validation

I have a method I'm using to validate user-inputted values in a program. Whenever the user inputs a string into a JOptionPane, I call this method and pass in the inputted string, plus the maximum and minimum values I need their input to be between. First I check if the input is an integer by trying to parse the input string and catching exceptions, then I check if the integer is between the min and max. My problem is that if the user inputs another incorrect non-integer value after being prompted, I don't know how to check if the new value is correct or not. Here is the method, can anybody help?

```
int checkInput(String input, int min, int max) {
        Boolean isInteger = false;
        Boolean inputAccepted = false;
        int userInput = 0; //will be set later
        while (!isInteger) {
            try
            {
                userInput = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter only integers between " + min + " and "+ max + "."));
                isInteger = true; //the problem here is that it assumes the user inputted a correct value after being prompted... what if they enter another incorrect value?
            }
        }
        while (!inputAccepted) {
        if (userInput < min || userInput > max) 
        {
                userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter only integers between " + min + " and "+ max + "."));
        }
        else 
        {
            inputAccepted = true;
        }
        }
        return userInput;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could check after each value being entered by user?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm unfamiliar with the try and catch statements, so I'm unsure how to do that while still making the loop check the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main problem is that you have a method whose job isn't simple and well-defined.  It looks like you have a statement *outside* this method that inputs a number; but `checkInput` has two jobs: making sure the number is valid, and inputting more numbers until it is.  This is a problem in two ways: your code that does the input is duplicated in two places, and you have a method whose responsibility isn't clear.

Instead, try writing a method that just checks whether the input is valid, and returns `true` or `false`.  I'd change the name to `isValidInput`.  The caller would then have a loop that would perform the input, make sure it's valid, and go back if it isn't.

Usually I wouldn't answer a question like this by pointing to flaws in your design.  But I think that in this case, if you rethink your design, your question will answer itself.  (That's often the case when you design things correctly--things fall into place.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was trying to do too many things in one method. Very clear and helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your checkInput() function should throw its own exception if the input is not correct. Spliting the code into a validator and a parser would result in parsing the input twice.